# yml file and mongoClient library

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I create a database.  I'm using application yml with

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://login:passwortd@mongo1/cars_new_model
```

and I wrote the following method

```
 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(XXX);
```

How to get database name from URI(yml file) and use it instead of XXX?

Answer (score 0):

db provided in URI is database used for connection, not necessary for query. The conf equivalent object is spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database.

That's why you have to provide database name when you create a Database object in java code. (a user (your java application) can be connected through a database, and access to some others). [From mongoDB Reference :](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

> /database     Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the
>   connection string includes authentication credentials in the form of
>   username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection
>   string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin
>   database.